# GUI Miner for OS X?

Tags: mac, mining-software, guiminer

I'm pretty new to the world of Bitcoin; though, a few months back I tried mining. I had everything working, but then I stopped.. Anyway, now I'd like to start up again, though I've wiped my computer and reinstalled OS X since then.
I had been using a GUI (GPU) Miner, but now I have no idea how to find it.. I think it had something to do with poclbm, but I can't be sure... Anyway, if anyone has had any luck with one, please inform me.
Thanks.

Btw: I'm running 10.7.4

Answer (score 5):

I guess you are referring to [GUIminer](https://bitcointalk.org/?topic=3878.0).

I would also recommend looking at the excellent [BitMinter](http://bitminter.com) miner, which has a nice GUI and runs great on Mac OS X. I should probably mention that I made it. ;)

Comment: Dr. Haribo -- thanks for Bitminter. Easy and works well

Answer (score 5):

MacMiner is the first and best native Mac GUI for bfgminer, cgminer and cpuminer

[MacMiner website](http://macminer.fabulouspanda.com/macminer/)

Comment: Agree with John.  I had issues authenticating when I used Asteroid.

Answer (score 1):

I use [DiabloMiner](https://github.com/Diablo-D3/DiabloMiner). Here are some [quick start instructions](https://github.com/Diablo-D3/DiabloMiner/wiki) for it.